# SVG image as Page Background xamarin

Tags: image, svg, xamarin.forms

How can I set an svg image as the page background in xamarin.forms?
I have tried to use

```
BackgroundImage = "image.svg";
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Not every Xamarin Forms platform supports SVG, so that won't work.  You can only use PNG or JPG, or write a custom platform rendered for SVG.

Comment: Can i set svg imge background image by writing custom renderer?

Comment: Is there any post or blog releted to this

Comment: You would need to write a custom page renderer and figure out how to draw the background as an SVG.  This is probably a fairly advanced problem to tackle.

Comment: can i convert svg image to FileImageSource in xamarin.forms?

Answer (score 0):

You may use a component name '[XamSvg](https://components.xamarin.com/view/XamSvg)' on xamarin component store. This component can use svg as an image on every plaform including xamarin.forms .

Comment: i am using https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/tree/master/SVG and it is working fine for images which are there inside any layout or child of some layout but not able to set svg image as page background image

Comment: Does XamSvg have a cache?